# how to speed up a sort algorithm using thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am working on an assignment where the goal is to speed up a quick sort process by creating multiple threads. However i cannot figure out how to speed up this process. I apply the threads allowed at the start however it only seems to slow the program down?

basically the goal is to sort a simple array by using the traditional recursive quick sort. But like I had stated previously that only seems to slow it down when i use the clock() library to time its performance. any suggestions? or is there something else that i need to do with the threads? I will upload my full source code here:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
static int maxThreads = 4;
#define SORT_THRESHOLD      40
//#includes==========
void *blin();
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
void *send(void *);

static int used = 0; 
static int reached = 0;
int doit = 0;
int threadNo = 0;

typedef struct _sortParams {
    char** array;
    int left;
    int right;
} SortParams;

static void insertSort(char** array, int left, int right) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        char* pivot = array[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= left && (strcmp(array[j],pivot) > 0)) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j--;
        }
        array[j + 1] = pivot;
    }
}





int going = 0;
int blins = 0;



void *send(void * p) {
    SortParams* params = (SortParams*) p;
    char** array = params->array;
    int left = params->left;
    int right = params->right;
    int i = left, j = right;
    
    if (j - i > SORT_THRESHOLD) {           
    /* if the sort range is substantial, use quick sort */

        int m = (i + j) >> 1;               /* pick pivot as median of         */
        char* temp, *pivot;                 /* first, last and middle elements */
        if (strcmp(array[i],array[m]) > 0) {
            temp = array[i]; array[i] = array[m]; array[m] = temp;
        }
        if (strcmp(array[m],array[j]) > 0) {
            temp = array[m]; array[m] = array[j]; array[j] = temp;
            if (strcmp(array[i],array[m]) > 0) {
                temp = array[i]; array[i] = array[m]; array[m] = temp;
            }
        }
        pivot = array[m];

        for (;;) {
            while (strcmp(array[i],pivot) < 0) i++; 
            /* move i down to first element greater than or equal to pivot */
            while (strcmp(array[j],pivot) > 0) j--; 
            /* move j up to first element less than or equal to pivot      */
            if (i < j) {
                char* temp = array[i];      /* if i and j have not passed each other */
                array[i++] = array[j];      /* swap their respective elements and    */
                array[j--] = temp;          /* advance both i and j                  */
            } else if (i == j) {
                i++; j--;
            } else break;                   /* if i > j, this partitioning is done  */
        }
        

        if (blins < 1) {
            blins++;
            SortParams first;  first.array = array; first.left = left; first.right = j;
            int ex;
            pthread_t thred[2];
            pthread_create(&thred[0], NULL, send, &first);
            pthread_join(thred[0], NULL);
            
        SortParams second; second.array = array; second.left = i; second.right = right;
        pthread_create(&thred[1], NULL, send, &second);
            pthread_join(thred[1], NULL); 
        
        } else {
        
        
        SortParams first;  first.array = array; first.left = left; first.right = j;
        send(&first);                  /* sort the left partition  */
        
        SortParams second; second.array = array; second.left = i; second.right = right;
        send(&second);                 /* sort the right partition */        
        
    }   
        
        

                
    } else insertSort(array,i,j);           /* for a small range use insert sort */
}

int main() {

    int count = 100000;
    char * array[count];  
    char * random[10] = {"asdfs", "wesasd", "asded", "aaddsdaa", "dsfs", "av", "bb", 
    "zz", "das", "efdxse"};
    int r = 0;
    for(int ni = 0; ni < count; ni++) {
        r = (rand() % 4);
        char string[100];
        strcpy(string, "");
        int b = (rand() % 50)+1;
        for (int bb = 0; bb < b; bb++) {
            r = (rand() % 4);
            if (r == 0) {
                strcat(string, "a");
            }
            if (r == 1) {
                strcat(string, "b");
            }
            if (r == 2) {
                strcat(string, "c");
            }
            if (r == 3) {
                strcat(string, "d");
            }
            if (r == 4) {
                strcat(string, "e");
            }
        }
        array[ni] = malloc(sizeof(string));
        strcpy(array[ni], string);      
    }
    
    clock_t t;
    
    t = clock();
    SortParams parameters; // declare structure
    parameters.array = array; parameters.left = 0; parameters.right = count - 1;
    //sleep(5);
    send(&parameters);
    
    t = clock() - t;
    
    double total = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    
    printf("%f \n", total);

    char ** jink = parameters.array;
    
    
    for (int ni = 0; ni < count/10; ni++) {
        printf("%s \n", jink[ni]);
    }
    // */
    
    
    for (int ni = 0; ni < count; ni++) {
        free(array[ni]);
    } printf("%f \n", total);

    

    return 0;
}
```

you should be able to simply copy/paste and it should work but as you can see i have created 2 threads but it's slower than with no threads.

Comment: give me just one moment i will upload it in a minute

Comment: Many factor are listed in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334109/quick-sort-with-multithreading-in-c). it's about C++ but you still can refer to it.

Comment: So you launch a thread by `pthread_create` and then immediately wait for it to finish with `pthread_join`. That's a more expensive version of just calling the code in question. If you want a speedup, you have to launch multiple threads at once, each working on a different piece of the data, then wait for them all to finish.

Comment: how is it that i immediately wait for it to finish? how can i make all of them run at once and wait for them as well?

Comment: @itsMe dratenik suggests instead of `create1; join1; create2; join2` to do `create1; create2; join1; join2`. But spawning too many threads is a bad idea. Check the answers mentioned by SOFuser above.

Comment: @itsMe do you know what pthread_join does?

Comment: makes the thread do its work?

Comment: I have searched through the other pages but to no avail still have not found anything that can speed up the process.

Comment: why would multiple threads speed up sort of a tiny array that fits in the cache of 1 CPU?

Comment: I do not know but wouldn't it logically speed it up because a thread creates another process??

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the main problem with the analogy.

You have a pile of sheets each with the number. The pile is unordered and you need to sort it.

### Sequential

You split the pile into two. Order them and then combine ordered piles into one big pile. You cannot put all sheets on your table as it is small. So you can only get say 20 sheets at once. When you need to sort the pile larger than 20 sheets you temporarily store what does not fit on the table in the box.

### Parallel

Every time you split the pile into two piles you call the courier service. It arrives in say 15 minutes and you send two piles to two of your friends who live on the other side of the town. Your friends sort the piles (and if they are large enough they also split them and send the piles to their friends and so on) and then they send sorted piles back to you using courier service. You need to wait until all the pile arrive from your friends before you can combine and sort them.

You can see that if you have just 10 sheets to sort (or even 1000) it will be much quicker to do that alone. All the overhead of the coordination, sending data to other side of the town is very large even that your friends (and their friends) can do the work (that is sort sheets) in parallel.

In order to get any visible speedup you need that your pile is large enough so that gain from introducing parallelization overweights the need to start new threads and synchronize their work (delay the courier services introduce).

Also in your current implementation you do not even do work in parallel. As starting a thread and then joining it immediately is similar to sending the first pile to your friend and then waiting for the result from your first friend before you send the second pile to your second friend. If you do this yourself it will be much more quicker for any size of the pile.

### What to do?

First of all you need to test this on some large data to see the gains.

Secondly there is no sense to create threads more than you have executors that is cores in you system. After you created that many threads they should just sort what they have without spawning any new threads.

You really need to make sure that threads do the work in parallel. This is the only place which works in your favour and the only source of the speedup of the parallel algorithm. All other factors work against you.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal improvement in your code is to sort the both parts in parallel and then join both threads:

```
    ...
    if (blins < 1) {
        blins++;
        SortParams first;  first.array = array; first.left = left; first.right = j;
        int ex;
        pthread_t thred[2];
        pthread_create(&thred[0], NULL, send, &first);   // start first thread

    SortParams second; second.array = array; second.left = i; second.right = right;
    pthread_create(&thred[1], NULL, send, &second);     // start second thread
    pthread_join(thred[0], NULL);                       // wait for first thread
        pthread_join(thred[1], NULL);                   // wait for second thread

    } else {
    ...
```

In my tests, the gain is between 50% and 30%. But using threads on a recursive processing is *brave*. I would instead have fixed the number of working threads (number of cores or hardware threads -1?) split the array in that number of chunks and have one thread per chunk. Then you only merge the sorted chunks

Comment: did you really see improved performance?? for some reason on my system granted i am using a vm I saw no improvement in performance what so ever.